# Display local file system image with cordova on IOS

Tags: ios, cordova, filesystems

My ( cordova ) app shall download an image from remote, store it persistent on local filesystem and display it. Downloading and storing is no problem. The images are created an the source attributes are set. But what type of URL I ever will use, the image is not displayed. I try to get this work for IOS in a native device.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <title>The App</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: cdvfile: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval' https://www.adomain.de; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://www.adomain.de; media-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://adomain.de; connect-src 'self' https://www.adomain.de; font-src 'self' data: https://www.adomain.de; img-src * filesystem: data: cdvfile:">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="links"></div>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="public/js/test/test.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

test.js:

```
var oRessources = {
  ressourcesDir:false,
    init:function(){                                
    function initFS(success){
        window.requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
        window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fs) {
            success();
        });
    }
    initFS(oRessources.createRessourcesDir);
    },
    createRessourcesDir:function(){                    
    resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, function(dirEntry){
            console.log('datadirectory');
            console.log(dirEntry);
            dirEntry.getDirectory(
                'ressources/',
                {create:true}, 
                function(dirEntry){
                    oRessources.ressourcesDir = dirEntry;
                    oRessources.download();
                },
                function(error){
                    console.log('error');
                    console.log(error)
                }
            );                              
        },
        function(dirEntry){
            console.log('error');
        }
    );
    }, 
    download:function(){
    var target = "e44498f0b0964152632bd0c82342914b859c543e.jpeg"
    oRessources.ressourcesDir.getFile(
        target, 
        { create: true, exclusive: false }, 
        function (fileEntry) {  
            console.log('file created');
            console.log(fileEntry);
            var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

            oReq.open("GET", "https://www.adomain.de/api/public/content_images/"+target, true);
            oReq.responseType = "blob";
            oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
                var blob = oReq.response; 
                if (blob) {                 
                    fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {                      
                        fileWriter.onwriteend = function (e) {
                            fileEntry.getMetadata(function(meta){
                            console.log(meta);
                            }, function(error){

                            });

                            var link = document.createElement("A");
                            link.appendChild(document.createTextNode(fileEntry.toInternalURL()));
                            link.href = fileEntry.toInternalURL();
                            document.getElementById('links').appendChild(link);

                            var image = document.createElement("IMG");
                            image.src = fileEntry.toInternalURL();
                            document.getElementById('links').appendChild(image);

                            var link2 = document.createElement("A");
                            link2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(fileEntry.toURL()));
                            link2.href = fileEntry.toURL();
                            document.getElementById('links').appendChild(link2);

                            var image2 = document.createElement("IMG");
                            image2.src = fileEntry.toURL();
                            document.getElementById('links').appendChild(image2);  

                            var link3 = document.createElement("a");
                            link3.appendChild(document.createTextNode(fileEntry.toURL().replace("///", "//") ));
                            link3.href = fileEntry.toURL().replace("///", "//");
                            document.getElementById('links').appendChild(link3);

                            var image3 = document.createElement("IMG");
                            image3.src = fileEntry.toURL().replace("///", "//");
                            document.getElementById('links').appendChild(image3);  

                            link4 = document.createElement("A");
                            link4.appendChild(document.createTextNode(fileEntry.fullPath ));
                            link4.href = fileEntry.fullPath;
                            document.getElementById('links').appendChild(link4);

                            var image4 = document.createElement("IMG");
                            image4.src = fileEntry.fullPath;
                            document.getElementById('links').appendChild(image4);  

                            console.log(blob);
                            link5 = document.createElement("A");
                            link5.appendChild(document.createTextNode(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob) ));
                            link5.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                            document.getElementById('links').appendChild(link5);              

                            var image5 = document.createElement("IMG");
                            image5.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                            document.getElementById('links').appendChild(image5); 

                            var readerBlob = new FileReader();                                
                            readerBlob.onload = function(event){
                                console.log('dataURL2');
                                //console.log(readerBlob.result);
                                var image6 = document.createElement("IMG");
                                image6.src = readerBlob.result;
                                document.getElementById('links').appendChild(image6);
                            };
                            console.log('dataURL1');
                            readerBlob.readAsDataURL(blob);

                        };
                        fileWriter.onerror = function (e) {
                            // you could hook this up with our global error handler, or pass in an error callback
                            console.log('Write failed: ' + e.toString());
                        };
                        fileWriter.write(blob);
                    });

                } else console.error('we didnt get an XHR response!');
            };
            oReq.onerror = function (oEvent) {
                if(oRessources.loadingStack.length > 0){
                    //oRessources.download();
                }else{
                    oRessources.loading = false;
                }
            }
            oReq.send(null);
        }, 
        function (error) {
            console.log('error creating file');
            console.log(error);
        }
    );
    }

};  

document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    console.log('DEVICE READY');
    oRessources.init();
}, false);


window.onerror = function(message, url, lineNumber){
    console.log('Error: '+message+' in '+ url + ' at line '+lineNumber);
}
```

config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="de.app.app" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>App</name>
    <description>
        App
    </description>
    <author email="mail@nils-fett.de" href="http://www.adomain.de">
        Nils Fett
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <access origin="cdvfile://*" />
    <access origin="file://*/*" />
    <access origin="file:///*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <allow-intent href="file://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="file:///*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="cdvfile:*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="file://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="file:///*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="cdvfile:*" />
    <allow-origin href="file://*/*" />
    <allow-origin href="file:///*/*" />
    <allow-origin href="cdvfile:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <access origin="*" />
        <access origin="cdvfile://*" />
        <access origin="file://*/*" />
        <access origin="file:///*/*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <allow-intent href="file://*/*" />
        <allow-intent href="file:///*/*" />
        <allow-intent href="cdvfile:*" />
        <allow-navigation href="file://*/*" />
        <allow-navigation href="file:///*/*" />
        <allow-navigation href="cdvfile:*" />
        <allow-origin href="file://*/*" />
        <allow-origin href="file:///*/*" />
        <allow-origin href="cdvfile:*" />
        <splash height="1024" src="lobbe-logo-768x1024.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="2048" src="lobbe-logo-1536x2048.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="1536" src="lobbe-logo-2048x1536.png" width="2048" />
    </platform>
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="Orientation" value="default" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="local" />
    <preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="library" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <feature name="File">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFile" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="FileTransfer">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFileTransfer" />
    </feature>
    <icon src="lobbe.png" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="~1.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~2.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-email-composer" spec="~0.8.11" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="~6.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="~2.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="~2.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~5.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-webserver" spec="~1.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.3.3" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="~4.2.1" />
</widget>
```

I think its a kind of restriction added in a newer IOS Version. I heard of a issue of the WKWebView, but threads read that this problem should be solved. Any ideas?

UPDATE:

So sorry, there was no problem with cordova or iOS or filesystem. The problem was, that the image URL were redirected to a html page. So I downloaded HTML and tried to dispay it as image. The code works. toInternalURL, toURL, createObjectURL and readAsDataURL work perfect.

Comment: can you try to add `'self'` to the img-src section of the Content-Security-Policy meta tag? Also, if you try to do remote debug of the app in desktop Safari, it should tell you the problem with the CSP

Comment: Thanks. Added 'self' to img-src. Remote Debog said: blob image rejected, because of missing in CSP. I fixed it by adding blob: too. The toURL() version with 2 slashes were not found as expected. But the toURL() version and the toInternalURL() and the blob version are fine. STATUS 200 loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So sorry, there was no problem with cordova or iOS or filesystem. The problem was, that the image URL were redirected to a html page. So I downloaded HTML and tried to dispay it as image. The code works. toInternalURL, toURL, createObjectURL and readAsDataURL work perfect.